# How do I ignore the yield value from a java stored procedure in cypher (neo4j)?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, java-stored-procedures

I have a CYPHER statement which first nearly matches every node in my graph.

```
MATCH (n:node) CALL procedure(n) YIELD node RETURN node
```

This blows up my memory (within python) because the response is so large. If I don't need or want the yielded value of the procedure, is it possible to tell neo4j using cypher not to return it?

When I try things like `YIELD NULL RETURN NULL` or similar variations, I get errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With my experience with Neo4J stored procedures, you must acknowledge the YIELD of the procedure, but you don't necessarily have to use it.  For example:

```
MATCH (n:node) CALL procedure(n) YIELD node return null limit 1;
```

The limit 1 is to prevent a null from being returned for however many results are returned by the procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
MATCH (n:node) CALL procedure(n) YIELD node RETURN count(node)
```

The result set is only a integer number.